# How can I prevent Google Drive and OneDrive from adding symlinks to my home folder?

Tags: macos

When I log in to Google Drive or OneDrive, they create symbolic links in my home folder to `/Users/me/Library/CloudStorage/[Google Drive or OneDrive]`. These links in my home folder have spaces in them and are not named concisely, which is inconvenient when working in terminal. If I rename or delete these links, Google Drive and OneDrive create them again with the default names the next time either program is restarted. Even if I choose a different "location" for OneDrive (which is really just where to create the symlink to `CloudStorage`), it still creates the symlink with a horrible name in my home folder, and Google Drive's location cannot be changed at all.

How can I prevent these programs from creating unwanted folders in my home folder (or can a script do something that will have the same effect)? Ultimately I would like there to simply be symlinks named `GoogleDrive` and `OneDrive` in my home folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This also annoys me. I haven't found a solution to prevent this but my hack is to have a cron job that deletes them (I have a personal drive and my work one). I have the cron job running four times a day but depending on how much it annoys you and how frequently you restart your machine or Google Drive you set  the frequency differently.  There must be a better way.

Adding detail to make the Community bot nanny happy, assuming you know how to use a terminal.

I create a script in an appropriate place. I put it in `/Users/scott/lib/bin/rmgoogle.sh`, but anywhere sensible for you will do.

```
#!/bin/zsh

/bin/rm -f xxx@yyyy\ -\ Google\ Drive
/bin/rm -f aaa@bbbb\ -\ Google\ Drive
```

and make it executable `chmod a+x /Users/scott/lib/bin/rmgoogle.sh`

Then I create an entry in the cron table

```
crontab -e
```

and add the following entry

```
55 9,12,15,17 * * *  /Users/scott/lib/bin/rmgoogle.sh
```

and then save. What this does is run my script at 9:55,12:55,15:55 and 17:55 each day. Change as desired.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).